# Cuda and/or OpenGL for geometric image transformation

Tags: opengl, image-processing, cuda

My question concerns the most efficient way of performing geometric image transformations on the GPU. The goal is essentially to remove lens distortion from aquired images in real time. I can think of several ways to do it, e.g. as a CUDA kernel (which would be preferable) doing an inverse transform lookup + interpolation, or the same in an OpenGL shader, or rendering a forward transformed mesh with the image texture mapped to it. It seems to me the last option could be the fastest because the mesh can be subsampled, i.e. not every pixel offset needs to be stored but can be interpolated in the vertex shader. Also the graphics pipeline really should be optimized for this. However, the rest of the image processing is probably going to be done with CUDA. If I want to use the OpenGL pipeline, do I need to start an OpenGL context and bring up a window to do the rendering, or can this be achieved anyway through the CUDA/OpenGL interop somehow? The aim is not to display the image, the processing will take place on a server, potentially with no display attached. I've heard this could crash OpenGL if bringing up a window.

I'm quite new to GPU programming, any insights would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using the forward transformed mesh method is the more flexible and easier one to implement. However performance wise there's no big difference, as the effective limit you're running into is memory bandwidth, and the amount of memory bandwidth consumed does only depend on the size of your input image. If it's a fragment shader, fed by vertices or a CUDA texture access that's causing the transfer doesn't matter.

> If I want to use the OpenGL pipeline, do I need to start an OpenGL context and bring up a window to do the rendering,

On Windows: Yes, but the window can be an invisible one.

On GLX/X11 you need an X server running, but you can use a PBuffer instead of a window to get a OpenGL context.

In either case use a Framebuffer Object as the actual drawing destination. PBuffers may corrupt their primary framebuffer contents at any time. A Framebuffer Object is safe.

> or can this be achieved anyway through the CUDA/OpenGL interop somehow?

No, because CUDA/OpenGL interop is for making OpenGL and CUDA interoperate, not make OpenGL work from CUDA. CUDA/OpenGL Interop helps you with the part you mentioned here:

> However, the rest of the image processing is probably going to be done with CUDA.

BTW; maybe OpenGL Compute Shaders (available since OpenGL-4.3) would work for you as well.

> I've heard this could crash OpenGL if bringing up a window.

OpenGL actually has no say in those things. It's just a API for drawing stuff on a canvas (canvas = window or PBuffer or Framebuffer Object), but it doesn't deal with actually getting a canvas on the scaffolding, so to speak.

Technically OpenGL doesn't care if there's a window or not. It's the graphics system on which the OpenGL context is created. And unfortunately none of the currently existing GPU graphics systems supports true headless operation. NVidia's latest Linux drivers may allow for some crude hacks to setup a truly headless system, but I never tried that, so far.

Comment: Thank you, based on your answer I think pure CUDA is the way to go.